# $C^1[0,1] \subset C^0[0,1]$ is not a closed subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to prove that $C^1[0,1] \subset C^0[0,1]$ is not a closed subspace.

I guess I can think of a sequence of functions in $C^1[0,1]$ that converges to a function that is continuous but not differentiable. I thought of maybe having a sequence converge to Thomae's function that is continuous only at irrationals so not differentiable, but couldn't find a sequence that does so.
Can someone help me out?

Also, the second part of the question asks to show that $\frac{d}{dx}: C^1[0,1] \to C^0[0,1]$ is bounded if $C^1[0,1]$ is given the $||f||_{C^1} = \sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}(|f(t)|)+\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}(|f'(t)|)$ norm but not if it is given the $C^0$ norm, and asks if the function is onto.

I have no idea how to start the second part of the question. Could someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: converges in what sense ? point-wise ? or for some $L^p([0,1])$ norm ? and the sequence of derivatives converges point-wise but uniformly to some function then that limit is $C^1$

Comment: It is impossible to find a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C^0([0,1])$ so that $f_n \to f$ in $\sup$ norm and $f$ is not continuous. It's because $f_n \to f$ in $\sup$ norm implies that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Since each $f_n$ is conintuous, this implies that $f$ is continuous too. Thus, in particular, you cannot find a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C^1([0,1])$ so that $f_n$ converges uniformly to the Thomae's frunction.

Comment: @JohnMa Then do you suggest any other counterexample?

Comment: Like Robert suggested, try to find a seuqnece of continuously differentiable function $\{f_n\}$ which converges to $|x-1/2|$, which is not continuous (pictorially) it is quite plausible to find this, as one can smooth out the corner at $1/2$.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you so much. Do you have an idea for the second part of the question? That's what really is bothering me lol

Comment: Regarding the second  part, let $A_n=(2 n+1/2)\pi.$ Let $f_n(x)=x\sin 1/x$ for $x\in [1/A_n,1]$ and $f_n(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1/A_n).$ Then $f_n\in C^1[0,1].$ With the $C_0 $ norm,  the set $\{\|f'_n\|\; /\; \|f_n\|\}_{n \in N}$  is  unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You want your sequence to converge to a function that is continuous everywhere, not just at irrationals, but not differentiable.  $|x - 1/2|$ comes to mind.

The first part of the second part is easy: just compare $\|f'\|_{C^0}$ and $\|f\|_{C^1}$.

Comment: Sorry, would you care to elaborate? I appreciate it.

Comment: Elaborate on which part?

Comment: I might not seeing the obvious right now but how comparing ||f'||_{C^0} and ||f||_{C^1} leads boundedness

Comment: Definition: An operator $T$ (from  normed space $X$ to normed space $Y$) is bounded if there is a constant $C$ such that for all $x \in X$, $\|Tx\|_Y \le C \|x\|_X$.